# Angular.js uncaught error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make a page using angular js and it gives me this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=store&p1=Error%3A%2…F%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fhp%2FDesktop%2FAngular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)

here is my code:

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', ['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
    this.products = gems;
    });
    var gems = [
        {
        name: 'Dodecahedron', 
        price: 2.95, 
        description: 'Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Dodeca is one of those gems.', 
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: true,
        },
        {
        name: 'Pentagonal Gem', 
        price: 5.95, 
        description: 'Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Dodeca is one of those gems.', 
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: true,  
        },
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> </head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you bind the controller to the view? I can't see any ng-controller in the template nor routes configuration.

Comment: Its off-topic: "Why isnt my code running .."

Comment: @Dario i updated the question but it didnt work either it has the same error

Comment: Could it be because of you are trying to make alias for controller same as your app "store"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not invoking your immediately invoked function, it should be:

```
(function () {

   //your code as it is...

})();
```

(note the `()` at the very end).

As a side note, you don't need to inject `ngRoute`.

Comment: :') could it be something that has to do with npm or no? or a configuration error?

Comment: Is the error the same you had before? Are the angular file loaded in the page? Sorry but I can't say more than this cause I can't reproduce the error anymore...